# .htaccess redirect if special characters in url while allowing some characters for some url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I don't have much knowledge about .htaccess url redirect.

I want to redirect url to 400 Error page if url has a special character in it
while allowing some characters like `?_-+=%&/` in url.

I am trying this way

```
RewriteRule ^([\W+]) /site/error/400/ [L]
```

This doesn't work.

Also tried following method.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\/) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/error/400/ [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This way all url's are redirecte to 400 error page.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this

Thanks.

**Update**

I want to return 400 error for these type of urls

```
http://localhost/site/?//any special character here except ?_-+=%&/
http://localhost/site/section/?//any special character here except ?_-+=%&/
http://localhost/site/section/page.html?//any special character here except ?_-+=%&/
http://localhost/site/section/category/?//any special character here except ?_-+=%&/
http://localhost/site/section/category/?order=id&sort=desc&rpp=10&page=2//any special character here except ?_-+=%&/
http://localhost/site/download/category/redirct.php?Id=5//any special character here except ?_-+=%&/
http://localhost/site/buy/category/redirct.php?Id=5//any special character here except ?_-+=%&/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^\w+=&/.-] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^\w+=%&/.-]
RewriteRule . /site/error/400/? [L,B,R=302]
```

Comment: Not redirecting this way

Comment: if I do like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/\w+=%&/-]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /site/error/400/ [L,B]` it gives 400 error for every url.

Comment: You need dot to be excluded also, see updated answer.

Comment: still not redirecting when special character are present in url

Comment: If you want redirection then use: `RewriteRule [^\w+=%&/.-] /site/error/400/ [L,B,R]` Also tell me what URL are you using to test it?

Comment: working but not working for these `'#=<>` characters and ` characters also

Comment: Actually `http://localhost/site/<>` did redirect. `#` is not special character since browser doesn't send `#` character or anything after it to web server. Also `\`` worked for me

Comment: Also not working on `/download` or `/buy` for which I want to allow these `+=%&/.-` characters only.

Comment: I didn't get. You should better be giving full URL that is not working.

Comment: See updated code and remember `%` is special character that is not allowed in QUERY_STRING anyway.

Comment: not working for `download` or `buy` urls, last two examples in update.

Comment: I clearly asked you provide my concrete example URL. ANY character doesn't make it concrete URL. Take an example `http://localhost/site/buy/category/redirct.php?Id=5*` and tell me what you want it be?

Comment: The example you mentioned is what I mean to tell, there can be any characters except allowed characters after `?` irrespective of how long the query string is or how many query parameter it has. If any special character is there then show 400 error.

Comment: Still didn't answer my direct question. What do you want `http://localhost/site/buy/category/redirct.php?Id=5*` to become?

Comment: `http://localhost/site/buy/category/redirct.php?Id=5*` redirect to `localhost/site/error/400/`

Comment: That's what happened with above rule. It got redirected to `http://localhost/site/error/400/` Do you have .htaccess in `/site/` or any other place also?

Comment: Redirect is happning every where except for the page that has `download` of `buy` fields if I change this `RewriteRule !^(download|buy) /site/error/400/? [NC,L,B,R=302]` to `RewriteRule !^(xxx|yyy) /site/error/400/? [NC,L,B,R=302]` then redirect happns for `download` or `buy` pages too.

Comment: Once again you are not making sense. You wrote `http://localhost/site/buy/category/redirct.php?Id=5* MUST redirect to localhost/site/error/400/` and I replied that is already happening with present rule.

Comment: Also looks like there is no difference between handling of `http://localhost/site/buy/category/redirct.php?Id=5*` and `http://localhost/site/category/redirct.php?Id=5*` so `/buy/` is not making any difference as per you question?

Comment: what I want is redirect any url which has special characters(in url as well as query) in it except allowed characters.

Comment: Right, except for pages that has `download or buy` in them.

Comment: Read your question again and see if your comment is matching question text. Did you not write: `http://localhost/site/buy/category/redirct.php?Id=5//any special character here except ?_-+=%&/` same as any other URL without buy/download above

Comment: same as any other URL without buy/download above I did not mention this after update.

Comment: Looks like you're not even trying to understand my question. How is `http://localhost/site/download/category/redirct.php?Id=5*` DIFFERENT from `http://localhost/site/category/redirct.php?Id=5*`?

Comment: I didn't see your updated answer, now its working every where except for `http://localhost/site/?;`

Comment: Note `%{QUERY_STRING}` condition doesn't have `%` unlike the 2nd condition

Comment: And there is a trailing `?` after `/400/?`

Comment: Try diff browser you made a copy/paste error probably

Comment: Sorry can't make wild guess as exact same code is already working for me.

Comment: using this rule `RewriteRule . /site/error/400/? [L]` its working everywhere except for `http://localhost/site/section/?;`, using this rule `RewriteRule . /site/error/400/? [L,B,R]` its working everywhere except for `http://localhost/site/?;`

Comment: You must have `R` flag for redirection rest is your local config since things are working fine.

Comment: where in local config?

Comment: Local config means you local host settings OR code OR something else local to you.

Comment: How can I allow these `()` too.

Comment: You also need to think rationally here. Look into the allowed characters list `[^\w=+&/.-]` Do we have semi colon here, obviously not. Apart from this whatever characters you want to allow just add them here inside this list.

Comment: I tried these solution already `[^\w+=&/.-()]` and `[^\w+=&/.-\(\)]`since it gives me internal server error that's why  I am asking you.

Comment: It would be: `[^\w+=&/.()-]` (Hyphen goes first or last)

Comment: Hi I am trying to allow spaces but can't get it right, can you help me, I have tried these ways but didn't work `[^\w+=&/.()\s-]`, `[^\w\s+=&/.()-]`, `[^\w+\s=&/.()-]`

Comment: So you want to allow spaces also in query string and in URI also?

Comment: I want spaces in query only. see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060414/allow-space-in-htaccess-url-redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this... That might work...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(download|/buy)$
RewriteRule ^([\W+]) /site/error/400/ [L]
```

[Find examples here...](http://www.wegtam.net/article/use-htaccess-rewritecond-and-rewriterule-redirect-your-urls-your-apache-webserver)