# Allow space in .htaccess url redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have redirected url with special characters to 400 error page using .htaccess which is working fine.

I am redirecting this way.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^\w+=&/.()-] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^\w+=&/.()-]
RewriteRule .? /site/error/400/? [L,B,R]
```

I want to allow spaces in query too, I am trying this way but its not working.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^\w\s+=&/.()-] [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^\w+=&/.()-\s] [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^\w+=&/.()\s-] [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^\w\d\s+=&/.()-] [OR]
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%20` for space:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^\w=+&/.%20()-] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^\w+=&/.()-]
RewriteRule ^ /site/error/400/? [L,B,R]
```

Comment: hi can you help me with this if you have time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096291/rewriting-subdomain-for-local-environment-via-htaccess

Comment: why doesn't the system think %20 is three separate characters? How would you specify three separate characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^\w\s+=&/.() -]
```

Comment: And if you place the space character in another place, at the beginning for example : RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^ \w+=&/.()-]