# Rewriting subdomain for local environment via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite subdomain for local environment using htaccess.

I have enabled virtual host in local and its working.

Rewrite

```
<link href="http://cdn.example.com/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to

```
<link href="http://cdn.localhost/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am trying this way but its not working

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn.example.com [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ cdn.localhost/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I just need to rewrite `http://cdn.example.com` to  `http://cdn.localhost`

`http://localhost` is loacted in `D:\wamp\www\example`

`http://cdn.localhost` is loacted in `D:\wamp\www\cdn`

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `http://` in your target URI and `R` flag will also be implied once you use `http://` in target URL.

Following rule should work:

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.example\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^ http://cdn.localhost%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: `Not working` doesn't give any info. Always provide detail. What URL did you? What error did you get? Is this the first rule in your .htaccess?

Comment: its not redirecting, and no error in logs. I have a file `http://localhost/example/test4.php` in which there is link to css like `<link href="http://cdn.example.com/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` but css is not applied, I can access css directly at `http://cdn.localhost/css.css` but when I go to this `http://cdn.example.com/css.css` url its not redirecting to `http://cdn.localhost/css.css`

Comment: also this is the first and only rule in .htaccess

Comment: Is `DocumentRoot` for `cdn.example.com` same as `DocumentRoot` of `localhost`? And is `css.css` at same place as `.htaccess`?

Comment: Create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://cdn.example.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: DocumentRoot is different,`http://localhost is loacted in D:\wamp\www\example` and `http://cdn.localhost is loacted in D:\wamp\www\cdn` css.css is at `D:\wamp\www\cdn\css.css`

Comment: from phpinfo I get this `D:/wamp/www/cdn` for `cdn.localhost` and for localhost I get this `D:/wamp/www `

Comment: But you need to place this rule in `DocumentRoot` of `cdn.example.com` NOT in the `cdn.localhost`

Comment: `cdn.example.com` is to be live website which I have not created yet as I first want to rewrite any live link to local host link.

Comment: I am accessing file locally at `http://localhost/example/test4.php` which has remote css link so I must put htaccess rule in the local site.

Comment: Ok then that is a big misunderstanding on your part. Rewrite rule cannot work for a site that has not been created. You can do this replacement in client side using Javascript probably but definitely not rewrite rule.

Comment: All I want is to change remote sub domain `cdn.example.com` to local subdomain `cdn.localhost` which I am accessing from `localhost`

Comment: Yes I understand but rewrite rules can only work on `cdn.example.com` server. You can do this replacement in client side using Javascript. I need to rush for some work, will check comments later.

Comment: Hi can you help me with this if you have time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219638/htaccess-switch-user-to-full-site-from-mobile-site-when-url-link-is-clicked